# Heat transfer for a copper rod

Tags: heat-transfer, temperature, thermal-conduction, convection

For a copper rod heated by a heat gun, why might the temperature of the rod continue to increase for a short time after the heat gun has been removed as the heat source? With reference to transient heat transfer

Comment: Why do you say the rod continues to increase in temperature when you remove the heat source? As the heat conducts along the rod some sections will get warmer and others will get cooler. But the bulk temperature will remain the same (or decrease if there is heat loss to the environment).

Answer (score 2):

If your temperature sensor is far away from the heat source, the detected temperature may increase even after the heat gun is turned off due to a preexisting temperature gradient evening itself out.